# shopping cart price rule - Free Gift at spend level (3 different spend levels)

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, free-gift

How would I go about creating a shopping cart price rule/rules by which if a customer spends over 500 they receive a free item, then when they spend 1,500 they receive a different gift?

The problem will be making sure the 500+ gift doesn't apply to a 1,500+ basket as well as the £1,500+ gift and the same with the £3,000+ gift - At the same time making sure there's a choice of gift for £1,500+ and £3,000+ baskets.

My current rule has the following conditions and actions:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you have to make a rule for each gift. And you should use two conditions on price to define a range of prices as condition. You might have to do some duplicate work but this is how I would do it.

Rule 1: If price is greater than 500 and smaller than 1500, add gift 1
Rule 2: If price is greater than 1500 and smaller than 3000, add gift 2
Rule 3: If price is greater than 3000, add gift 3